# Triggering event on radio button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a few radio  buttons, one of which is the 'other' button. If a user clicks 'other' I want to show a text box asking for more info. This is my HTML and JS:

```
    <div class="radio">
    <label><input type="radio" name="optradio">Friend</label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio">
    <label><input type="radio" name="optradio"> Worked together </label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio">
    <label><input type="radio" name="optradio"> Studied together</label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio">
    <label><input type="radio" name="other-radio" id="connection-invite-other-radio"> Other </label>
    </div>

   <div class="form-group" id="connection-invite-other">

    <input type="text" class="form-control" >
    </div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){


    if($('#connection-invite-other-radio').is(':checked')) {        
        $('#connection-invite-other').show();
        console.log("hi");
    }

    else {
        $('#connection-invite-other').hide();
    }

});
```

This however isn't working. Please help me understand if I'm doing something wrong. Thanks!

Comment: If you want to do *x* in response to a click, you have to put *x* inside a click handler function - your existing if/else runs *once,* when the document first loads. (Also, why does the "other" radio button have a different name attribute? Isn't it supposed to be part of the same group as the other radio buttons?)

Comment: Good point, thanks, I will change that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The `radio` needs to have the same `name`, in your case `optradio`.
2. You need to use a `change` event listener on all `radio` elements.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[type=radio]').change(function() {
    if ($('#connection-invite-other-radio').is(':checked')) {
      $('#connection-invite-other').show();
    } else {
      $('#connection-invite-other').hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="radio">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="optradio">Friend</label>
</div>
<div class="radio">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="optradio">Worked together</label>
</div>
<div class="radio">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="optradio">Studied together</label>
</div>
<div class="radio">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="optradio" id="connection-invite-other-radio">Other</label>
</div>
<div class="form-group" id="connection-invite-other">
  <input type="text" class="form-control">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `change` event of radio button to show hide div.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $('#connection-invite-other-radio').change(function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')) {        
        $('#connection-invite-other').show();
        console.log("hi");
    }

    else {
        $('#connection-invite-other').hide();
    }
   });    
});
```